# Add dynamic link to a file in a outlook 2007 template (.OFT)

Tags: outlook

Generate email using outlook 2007 template (OFT)

Have oft template, with file attachment. 
File appears to be embedded in the OFT. 
I want to add a link to the file on the filesystem because its getting updated i want to email it periodically (I want to be able to update the file. Then mail it along with updates. )

Want to create the template in Outlook, not in code

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that. You need to update the template when the file is changed on the disk. Or re-attach the file anew when a mail item is created.

You may find the [How To: Create a new Outlook message based on a template](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/31/outlook-create-message-based-on-template/) article helpful.